# Is there any ways to check statements after return in C?

Tags: c

This code can be compiled in C:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("Hello World");
    return 0;
    
    printf("shouldnt allow this line");
    return 1; //also this line
}
```

the line `printf("shouldnt allow this line");` and `return 1;` are unreachable. Is there any ways to check this during compilation with warning messages? Also, why does the compiler allows this?

Comment: Often, compilers will give warnings saying that certain portions of code are unreachable. I don't know off the top of my head what flags to set for gcc, but I'm pretty sure there's a way to do it. There's nothing syntactically incorrect here, just semantically incorrect.

Comment: It is actually useful for debugging sometimes - bugs me that Java etc don't let you do it - you need to comment out the remainder or stick it in `if (false) { ... }`

Comment: Prohibiting this would have made the language spec more complicated and harder to implement.

Comment: Almost all questions of the form "Why doesn't C work like I expect it to work?" can only be accurately answered with a statement of the form "Because that's what the standard says, and it's not going to change now." It also usually turns out that the question was really a possibly-unconscious attempt to lobby for a change which won't happen (because billions of lines of installed code), with the result that the answers end up attempting to justify a decision made decades ago. That's why so many questions of this form end up being closed as "primarily opinion-based".

Answer (score 3):

Unreachable code is not an error because:

1. It's often useful, especially as the result of macro expansion or functions which are only ever called in a way that makes some paths unreachable due to some of their arguments being constant or limited to particular range. For instance, with an inline version of `isdigit` that's only ever called with non-negative arguments, the code path for an `EOF` argument would be unreachable.
2. In general, determining whether code is unreachable is equivalent to the halting problem. Sure there are certain cases like yours that are trivial to determine, but there is no way you can specify something like "trivial cases of unreachable code are errors, but nontrivial ones aren't".

Comment: "there is no way you can specify something like "trivial cases of unreachable code are errors, but nontrivial ones aren't"" - sure you can, if you specify the exact types of trivial cases you prohibit. [Java does that](https://ideone.com/qkWgzw), for example.

Comment: This is true as far as it goes, but I don't think it's a very complete answer, since (other than the bit about macro expansion) the same is true in languages that *do* forbid examples like the OP's. (I assume that the OP's question is motivated by familiarity with such a language.) The important thing is a philosophical difference between C and (say) Java.

Comment: It would be possible to specify that code after a `return` statement in the same block is an error (with the right terminology that `if(x) return 0; y;` is not an error, etc.)

Comment: @M.M: Since this is C, I think you'd also want an exception whereby you *can* have a label immediately after a `return` statement, plus arbitrary code after that label.

Comment: @ruakh: definitely. Case labels, for example.

Comment: @user2357112: C lacks the formal machinery to do that in a meaningful way. And there would be all sorts of wacky questions like "is `if ((volatile int){1}) return; /* some more code here */` an error?"

Answer (score 1):

Broadly speaking, C does not aim to help a developer catch mistakes; rather, C trusts the developer to do a perfect job, just as it trusts the compiler to do a perfect job.

Many newer languages take a more active stance, aiming to protect the developer from his or herself — and plenty of C compilers will emit compile-warnings (which can typically be "promoted" to errors via command-line flags) — but the C community has never wanted the language to stop trusting developers. It's just a philosophical difference. (If you've ever run into a case where a language prevents you from doing something that seems wrong but that you actually have a good reason for, you'll probably understand where they're coming from, even if you don't agree.)

Comment: This is rubbish IMO, there are plenty of language features in C designed to catch mistakes, and plenty of support in compilers for detecting mistakes beyond what the standard requires.  And every language permits mistakes of some sort or another, that's inherent in the concept of actually being able to write a program

Comment: @M.M: I agree with all of your comment except the part where you called my answer rubbish. ;-)